# How can i take screenshot of a webpage contains Javascript?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4, canvas, d3.js, webpage-screenshot

I need to take a screenshot of a webpage by implementation the screenshot on a button click in an web application. I need it to work on client side completely and store the selected area to the clipboard.

Comment: Thanks...but i need to select a certain area of my web page and send that portion alone to the canvas and use it in clipboard, kindly let me know if you find answer..

Comment: Also useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912092/using-html5-canvas-javascript-to-take-screenshots/6678156#6678156

Comment: The question is also off-topic as it stands at the moment. Feel free to edit the question to meet [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), the ask to have it reopened.